# Stop Mouse Scrolling at a variable ID or class NOT a pixel number

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scrolltop, jquery-pagescroller

I'm trying to stop scrolling at a variable instead of a pixel measurement.

PINK is the top of my page YELLOW is nothing special, but RED is where I'm trying to stop the scrolling action using a variable to call an ID of my choice. The user should still be able to scroll up but never scroll beyond the red div.

I've found some examples using pixels but my page changes height, so I'm trying to target `id` from divs with a variable instead of a pixel position.

My broken Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mikeloucas/d7o8exub/52/

P.S. I'm making an animation so I'm trying to keep the user on the red div until they click the "stop the scroll" button. (I got that part working elsewhere, not here, but it's pixel-based.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var StartTop = $("#beginning").offset().top;

  /* $(document).scrollTop(StartTop); */
  var EndGame = $("#stopHere").height();

  $(document).on("scroll", function(e) {
    var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowScrollTop < EndGame) {
      $(document).scrollTop(EndGame);
    } else if (windowScrollTop > EndGame) {
      $(document).scrollTop(StartTop);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#beginning {
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.genBox {
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#stopHere {
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="beginning"></div>
<div class="genBox"></div>
<div class="genBox"></div>
<div id="stopHere"></div>
<div class="genBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the scroll position based on the position of the div? Not quite sure if that would be what you're looking for...

```js
const lowDivTop = document.getElementById('low').getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
document.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
    window.scrollTo(0, Math.min( lowDivTop - window.innerHeight, window.scrollY));
})
```

```css
#top, #mid, #low{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#top{
  background: yellow
}
#mid{
  background: orange
}
#low{
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div id='top'></div>
<div id='mid'></div>
<div id='low'></div>
```

Comment: Well let me give it a go regardless of what happens next, good looking out. :-)  back soon.

Comment: Looks like it its working. :-) I tried changing my screen size and THEN refreshing the browser and it worked every time. But If change my scree size WITHOUT refreshing the bowser, it wont scroll to the correct (initial) position. Over all, Ill try to sort that part out (sticking to its initial stop point). Im trying to idiot proof the screen in case a user load the screen and THEN resize it. Thanks a lot though your solution is alot smaller than my clunk of junk, LOL

Comment: Question: How do I add an unbind to a button to  turn this off? My OG code doesn't work with this new one:                                                                                                  
////////
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(window).unbind();
  });
});

Comment: Make a function `handleScroll(e)` for handling the scroll event. To activate it, add it to the event listener, ie `document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)`. To deactivate, simply remove it again `document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)`

Comment: I'll give it a go. :-) Thanks B!